# Payment Processor. MD5 Hash Removal/Disablement from Authorize.Net

Tags: payment-processor, authorize.net

Today Morning I got an Email from the authorize.net regarding MD5 Hash Removal/Disablement. Here what exactly they stated.

```
Authorize.Net is phasing out the MD5 based transHash element in favor 
of the SHA-256 based transHashSHA2. The setting in the Merchant 
Interface which controls the MD5 Hash option will be removed by the 
end of January 2019, and the transHash element will stop returning 
values at a later date to be determined.  

Merchants utilizing this feature will need to work with their web 
developer or solutions provider to verify if they are still utilizing 
MD5 based hash and if still needed to move to SHA-256 hash via 
Signature Key.
```

Currently I am using CiviCRM 4.7.29 version. Integrated with Drupal 7.

In payment Processors settings. I am using Authorize.Net as Payment Processor Type. And Using MD5 hashing also.

Now my question is. Does the latest version 5.9 supports this feature? Or Please let me know is their any other alternate solution.

Comment: This is the first I've heard about this, and I didn't see an issue on CiviCRM's issue tracker.  I [added one just now](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/39).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to your question, the immediate issue has been resolved.  Issue [financial#39](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13474) removes MD5 hashing from CiviCRM starting with the March release.

Note that Authorize.Net is removing the ability to ADD MD5 hashing to your account in January - but MD5 hashing won't stop working for several months after that.

Comment: I have applied the patch in "https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13474" to my Dev environment site. After that, I made contribution & registered to an event in a Test mode. Payment happening successfully and showing in the CiviCRM Contribution page. But Transaction details are not showing up in the Sandbox. I checked both settled and unsettled transaction, Thier is no record of the transaction what we have made</br>. Is this patch passed the QA?